# Extended neighborhood in Conways neighborhood not reading in custom agentset

Tags: netlogo

I am attempting to write a version of Conway's game of life that instead of looking at the neighboring 8 cells, looks at the neighboring 24 cells. (Instead of 1 square around the center, looks at 2).

I have followed some advice and set up a "neighbors24" agents that should look at the surrounding cells in a live-cell.

```
patches-own [
  living?         ;; indicates if the cell is living
  live-neighbors  ;; counts how many neighboring cells are alive
]

to setup-blank
  clear-all
  ask patches [ cell-death ]
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-random
  clear-all
  ask patches
    [ ifelse random-float 100.0 < initial-density
      [ cell-birth ]
      [ cell-death ] ]
  reset-ticks
end


to cell-birth
  set living? true
  set pcolor fgcolor
end

to cell-death
  set living? false
  set pcolor bgcolor
end

to go
  let neighbors24 patches with [abs pxcor <= 2 and abs pycor <= 2]
  ask patches
    [ set live-neighbors count neighbors24 with [living?] ]
  ask patches
    [ ifelse live-neighbors = 3
      [ cell-birth ]
      [ if live-neighbors != 2
        [ cell-death ] ] ]
  tick
end

to draw-cells
  let erasing? [living?] of patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor
  while [mouse-down?]
    [ ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor
      [ ifelse erasing?
        [ cell-death ]
        [ cell-birth ] ]
      display ]
end
```

While the code compiles correctly, its behavior is not at all what I expect it to be. For instance if I place 3 live cells within the 24 neighborhood radius, instead of a cell birth, all cells die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some minor adjustments to your `go` procedure with some input coming from the Moore & Von-Naumann neighborhood example from the NetLogo Model Library. For more details on the adjustments, please check the comment in the code below.

```
to go
  ;; creates a list with patches of the surrounding 24 patches 
  ;; with the caller included.
  let neighbors24 [list pxcor pycor] of patches with [abs pxcor <= 2 and abs pycor <= 2]

  ;; uncomment the line below, if you don´t want to consider the caller 
  ;; patch to adjust the neighbors24 set

  ;set neighbors24 remove [0 0] neighbors24

  ;; for illustration, shows the number of coordinates considered as neighbors
  ;show length neighbors24 

  ;; for illustration, shows the patch coordinates of the neighbors24 set
  ;show neighbors24 

  ask patches [ 
    ;; each patch checks the the "living" neighbors at the given coordinates (relative to this agent). 
    ;; Check documentation of "at-points"
    set live-neighbors count patches at-points neighbors24 with [living? = true]
  ]
  ask patches 
  [ ifelse live-neighbors = 3
    [ cell-birth ]
    [ if live-neighbors != 2
      [ cell-death ] ] ]

  tick
end
```

I did not extensively test the code, but it seemed alright with a low, random starting density of living patches ( 20-30% ). Please check the example screenshot of the first  rounds for 27% density.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All cells are dying because they are not counting the live cells around themself, but around the origin. Edit your code like this:

```
to go
  let neighbors24 patches with [abs pxcor <= 2 and abs pycor <= 2]
  type "Live patches near centre: " print count neighbors24 with [living?]
  ask patches
  ...
```

I have added a line that prints out what will be in the variable live-neighbors.

Have a look at how you are calculating neighbors24. You are using the coordinate values. So that is always the patches up to 2 patches around the origin (which is at 0,0). As I stated in my comment on your previous question, you need to look at the model called "Moore & van Nuemann example" in the models library. Just search for "Moore". That has code that will use the patch's own coordinates to centre the neighbourhood.

Note that you will also have to get the neighbourhood inside the `ask patches` as well.

Comment: I had a hunch that was what was going on, it seems I misinterpreted how the code was reading in the live cells. Thanks for the feed back!